# Is there a way to save specific cells source code to a file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am developing some functions in a notebook (easy to evaluate their performance) and would like to deploy part of them to a machine. This process is iterative. Is there a way to save only some of the cells to a file so it could be ran else where? (instead of selectively copying the cells of interest)

Comment: You could have a look at the %save magic (see `%see?`). This allows to save specific commands from the history to a python script.